# Почему не используют pt в качестве единицы измерения элементов?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

`pt` одинаково выглядит на любом экране так как не зависит от плотности пикселей, в отличии от `px`.

Почему никто их не использует? Есть какие то подводные камни о которых я не знаю?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Скажу за верстку, в большинстве своем я вообще использую `rem` и поэтому не задаюсь данным вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CSS `pt` вместо того чтобы зависеть от dpi, считается из пропорции `72pt = 96px`.

Поэтому его использование в стилях не для печати бессмысленно.